# Regexp в django-userena

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, django

Здравствуйте.

В коде предыдущим разработчиком было изменено регулярное выражение для создания нового пользователя:

```
#Signup
url(r'^(?P<username>.+?)/signup/complete/$',
```

В не измененной Userena вот такой паттерн [Строчка 40](https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena/blob/v1.1/userena/urls.py):

```
# Signup
url(r'^(?P<username>[\.\w]+)/signup/complete/$',
```

Помогите разобраться что же изменилось. Хочу выбросить изменения для более легкого апдейта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандартный шаблон пропускал только точку, латиницу, цифры  и знак подчеркивания в имени пользователя.
Новый шаблон пропускает что угодно, главное, чтобы оканчивалось на `/signup/complete/`
Например так:

```
Vasja'); DROP TABLE users;/signup/complete/
```

Дает ли это действительно возможность инъекции- вряд ли. Скорее всего таким способом хотели не заморачиваться с регулярками в роутере, если нужно было в логине разрешить например кириллицу или собаку.

Comment: Тоесть, если у меня пользователи из унаследованной БД с пробелами, астериксами, амперсандами и звездочками, то как раз нужно изменять шаблон? Наверное, тут(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/) я найду все ответы. Спасибо :)